# Export page numbers of references

Tags: cross-referencing, compiling

I would like to export the page numbers of all the inner references of my document. How can one achieve this? Equivalently, how can we export the section/chapter number of all the inner references?

For external references of the bibliography (I use bibtex), using the `\backref` command creates a `.brf` file  which contains this information.

---

**Edit:**
By inner references, I mean references to a label defined by `\label` and referred by `\ref`.
Consider for instance, the minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\section{One}
Here\label{here}

\newpage
\section{Two}

\newpage
\section{Three}
Here is \ref{here}.
\end{document}
```

I would like to retrieve that there is an inner reference from page 3 (Section 3) to page 1 (Section 1).

Comment: This information is stored in the `.aux` file, together with some other stuff, but it's all there.

Comment: I see `\newlabel` commands that creates the end-points of the inner references, but not the starting points of the references I made.

Comment: What do you mean with "export the page numbers"? May you please add some more information?

Comment: not sure i understand this exactly.  is what you want the chapter/section location where every `\ref` or `\eqref` appears?

Comment: @egreg: I added an example.

Comment: @wwjoze It's not clear how you want to use the information.

Comment: @egreg: I wanted to do a graph-style display of the references inside my document.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a complete solution as it is not clear to me how you want to actually use the gathered information, but it should give you some starting pointers how to obtain it.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\ref#1{\expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@firstoftwo{#1}%
% addition
   \protected@write\@auxout{}%
         {\string\usedlabel{#1}{\thepage}}}
\def\pageref#1{\expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname
                                   \@secondoftwo{#1}%
% addition
      \protected@write\@auxout{}%
         {\string\usedpagelabel{#1}{\thepage}}}

\def\usedlabel#1#2{\typeout{ref #1 on page #2}}
\def\usedpagelabel#1#2{\typeout{pageref #1 on page #2}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{A}\label{A}

text\label{B} see section~\ref{A}

\newpage

text referencing page~\pageref{B} in section~\ref{A}

\end{document}
```

In essense this changes `\ref` and `\pageref` to make a note in the `.aux` file looking like this:

```
\usedlabel{A}{1}
\usedpagelabel{B}{2}
```

I defined those commands to do a typeout, but anything is possible. Notice that the aux file is read in twice, once at the beginning and once at the end, so further work is necessary. Also not that in this simple approach it doesn't work with any packages that modify `\ref` in some way.

As a result of the above you get:

```
ref A on page 1
pageref B on page 2
ref A on page 2
```

on the screen and in the log.

### Update

I forgot to mention that patching `\ref` of course only works as long as one isn't using some package that modifies this command as well. So one example where this breaks is the `hyperref` package, that for good reasons provides its own (and completely different) implementation of `\ref`, so that the above modification is simply never used.

Looking quickly into `hyperref` code, the most likely candidate for hooking into seems to be `\T@ref` but I didn't do an exhaustive check, this may not be the best approach (and it probably doesn't work with all options that hyperref offers). Anyway, for me it worked:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \def\T@ref#1{%
     \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\usedlabel{#1}{\thepage}}%
      \Hy@safe@activestrue
      \expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@firstoffive{#1}%
      \Hy@safe@activesfalse
    }%
    \def\T@pageref#1{%
      \protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\usedpagelabel{#1}{\thepage}}
      \Hy@safe@activestrue
      \expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@secondoffive{#1}%
      \Hy@safe@activesfalse
    }%
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you found the way to write exactly the information to the `.aux` file.

Comment: @wwjoze having written some of it an being involved with it for 20+ year kind of helps :-)

Comment: This does not seem to work when I load the `hyperref` package. Do you know why?

Comment: @wwjoze yes, forgot to mention that redefinitions of commands of course only work as long as not something else is trying to do the same. This is why I said this is not a complete solution only some pointers how to work up a solution. Updated the answer to show one way to make it work with hyperref